# Using Dapper when table has more columns than class

Tags: c#, sql-server, dapper

In Dapper how do you ignore a table column during an insert?

I have a class with properties A,B,C and have a List of these.

Presume something like

```
class DTO 
{
    string A;
    string B;
    string C;
}
```

and the list is of type

```
List myList = new List<DTO>()
```

So with a line of sql like this to bulk insert the list into my table

```
sql="INSERT INTO TABLE VALUES (@A,  @B, @C)";
conn.Execute(sql, myList)
```

It works fine and inserts all my data when my table also has columns A,B,C.

But when my table has more columns, e.g. A,B,C,D I get the error: Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition

I know how to ignore class properties using the Dapper Contrib library, but not the other way round.

How can I do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes. I presumed saying my class properties match my table and I have a list of these and it works would imply this. My question is just about sql tables with extra columns not in a class.

Comment: I'm not going to push my edit again but just FYI: [Should 'Hi', 'thanks', taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts)

Comment: @rene I'm not saying thanks to an answer, I'm simply being polite with my question. Stackoverflow regex outs salutations, etc. It has no rules on thanks.

Comment: Yes, it has, i just linked you to it. But thanks.

Comment: I appreciate on the need to reduce text to make questions more readable, but it just seems impolite to end a sentence asking for somebody's time and effort without curtesy. There are many superfluous bits of text in questions and I figure 'thanks' wouldn't impose too much extra storage ;)

Comment: @Neil.  Stack Overflow has had this ethos for years.  The idea is to make these posts "articles."  Noise should be reduced to the minimum level possible.  If you want to say "Thanks," do it in comments; that's what they're there for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to enumerate your columns specifically, as in:

```
sql="INSERT INTO TABLE (column1name, column2name, column3name) VALUES (@A,  @B, @C)";
```

Alternatively, if your DTO contains a primary key, you can decorate your DTO with the following attributes:

```
[Table("TableName")]
class DTO 
{
    [Key]
    int id;
    string A;
    string B;
    string C;
}
```

and use `Insert()` from [Dapper.Contrib](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper/tree/master/Dapper.Contrib).

```
connection.Insert(dto);
```

Comment: Thanks, I was trying to avoid having to type everything in as in real world there are many, many columns. I thought there might be a way like how you can ignore class fields using the Dapper extension library., or perhaps a way to tell Dapper to simply match the provided properties and ignore everything else...

Comment: I'm already using contrib and already have my table attribute set, but when I read the documentation and help, when inserting Lists it reads as if you have to do the full INSERT statement. I'll give it try.

Comment: Dapper.Contrib writes its own SQL, based on the fields you provide in your DTO.